# Magnet links in Chrome, only some working

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink

I accidentally clicked "do nothing" and "remember my choice" for a magnet link to inspect item in CSGO (Steam link). Now, it does not work. I tried editing the "Local State" file in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data but even after setting it to "false" the Steam links does not work. Tried torrent magnets and they still work, so it seems to be related to Steam directly. Resetting all chrome settings and also re-installing chrome confirms this as it did not solve the issue either.

How can I fix this? For registry purposes, I'm on 64 but Win 10 PRO.

**PS! I searched for hours. I can only find solutions related to magnet links overall!**

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Searched "Steam" in Local State" file and set it to false (after closing chrome)